# Failed to resolve import "ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor" from "src/App.tsx". Does the file exist?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, vite, ckeditor5

I am trying to add a custom build built with the Ckeditor online builder to a react + vite app. I also used typescript

I unzipped the downloaded file and after trying to import the custom editor from the build and I got the error above.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to run `npm i ./ckeditor-custom-build`

Vite requires linked packages to be ESM, and unfortunately, the CKEditor build is not ESM yet.

Read more about it here - [Ckeditor documentation on vite](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/react.html) and [Vite documentation on linked dependencies](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#monorepos-and-linked-dependencies).

This is my solution below:

```html
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['ckeditor5'],
  },
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      include: [/ckeditor5/, /node_modules/],
    }
  }
})
```